# Timestamp conversion in Oracle for YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-timestamp

I'm trying to insert records with `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format into Oracle from Netezza, but I'm getting invalid date type.

How can I accomplish this one?

```
CREATE TABLE AM_PROGRAM_TUNING_EVENT_TMP1
(
    ST TIMESTAMP,
    ET TIMESTAMP,
    MAS_DIV_KEY INTEGER NOT NULL,
    SBSC_GUID_KEY INTEGER NOT NULL,
    STN_KEY INTEGER NOT NULL
 );


INSERT INTO  AM_PROGRAM_TUNING_EVENT_TMP1 VALUES('2012-03-28 11:10:00','2012-03-28 11:30:00',1,3636815,151);
```

Comment: Please post the INSERT statement you're using, the DDL for your table, and an example of the data.

Comment: My data is coming from a flat file... and I want to perform date transformation while inserting data...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO AM_PROGRAM_TUNING_EVENT_TMP1 
VALUES(TO_DATE('2012-03-28 11:10:00','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/22115/1

Answer (score 33):

Use [TO_TIMESTAMP](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm) function

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(date_string,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```