# Change from number to this date format(dd/mm/yyyy)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I receive this date(number) from Oracle database

> 0.002976190476190476

I'd like to change to this format: `dd/mm/yyyy`, using `Javascript` or `jQuery`.

How can I do?

Comment: Is that a date or a timespan? I've not seen a date format which uses a floating point before.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, it's a date. I receive this way from database.

Comment: Can you also tell what datetime it is? Refer following [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319935/timestamp-conversion-in-oracle-for-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-format) for reference.

Comment: @Rajesh, we use this format in Brasil.

Comment: My apologies, I meant, in JS timestamp `1451928337920` means `Mon Jan 04 2016 22:55:37 GMT+0530 (IST)`. So what datetime does this timestamp represents

Comment: @Rajesh, 04/01/2016 - This is the format desired

Comment: Are you sure the date (number) is correct? Shouldn't it be `> 0` or No of secs. in a year: `31536000000`?

Comment: @Rajesh, yes. I'm sure.

Comment: @pkt then I guess you will have to manually parse it. In such cases, I would recommend you to do it on database only, but if you want to try in JS, you can try something like **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/t2sgtd6d/1/)**.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @x NUMERIC(10,0);

SET @x = 20110501;

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), @x));
```

Result

```
2011-05-01 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: I'm guessing from the jQuery and Javascript tags, the OP wants to do it on the client.

Comment: Nikita, this way i'm go to convert in the database, but i need to convert it in my application.

Comment: I have edited my comment.
Also, found one more useful link - 
http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/date/source.html