# "Not a valid month" when getting a count by comparing timestamps

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to see how many items are older then 3 years. When I use

`select count (*) from ae_dt509 where field13 < to_timestamp( '2013-06-15 00:00:00', 'YY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS' )`

I get this error:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
select count (*) from ae_dt509 where field13 < to_timestamp( '2013-06-12 00:00:00', 'YY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS' )
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I am not sure whats wrong...

EDIT

I changed the code to correct the year:

`select count (*) from ae_dt509 where field13 < to_timestamp( '2013-06-15 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' )`

and I got the same error.

and then changed it by removing the qoutes around the date:

`select count (*) from ae_dt509 where field13 < to_timestamp( 2013-06-15 00:00:00, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' )`

and got

`Bind Variable "00" is NOT DECLARED`

Comment: Is it anything to do with the year being 4 digit but specified as YY?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319935/timestamp-conversion-in-oracle-for-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-format

Check the second answer. And @Charleh's comment is basically your answer.

Comment: @Charleh I changed year and I still have the same error

Comment: Can you update the question to show your new code?

Comment: Is `field3` an actual `timestamp` data type?  Or is it potentially a string that is supposed to represent a date or a timestamp?

Comment: Try `to_timestamp( '2013-06-15 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' )` or even `< add_months (systimestamp, -36)`

Comment: You also quietly changed the date from `12` to `15`. This suggests that you may be **retyping** code here rather than **copying and pasting** code here. Please only copy and paste. Otherwise, little differences creep in. Like the aforementioned `12` -> `15`

Comment: As a debug step, can you verify that `select to_timestamp( '2013-06-15 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) from dual` returns the expected result? If that works, the problem must be in your data.

Comment: @sstan - copied the wrong statement :-) - fixed

Comment: @HansKesting Your code worked so the problem does not lie with the data.

Comment: @AllieHart - yes, the problem does lie in the data, meaning the data **in the table** (ae_dt509 ). Can you answer the comment by Justin Cave?

Comment: @HansKesting It is a string.........

Comment: Then apparently (at least) one of those strings is invalid as a date.

Comment: Sstan had the solution. Thanks everyone for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that `field13` is not a date or timestamp field.

For example, if I run the following statement on my local server:

```
select * from (
  select '2013-06-12 00:00:00' as some_fake_date
  from dual
)
where some_fake_date > systimestamp
```

... I get the same error as you.

To fix your problem, wrap `field13` with `to_timestamp` and the appropriate format parameter:

```
where to_timestamp(field13, '<insert_correct_format_specifier>' < to_timestamp('2013-06-15 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

This of course means that your preformance will degrade if you were relying on an index on `field13`.  Ideally, you should fix the column type of `field13` to be a real date or timestamp.

Comment: Thanks, This will help until I fix the column

Answer (score 0):

The *select count (*) from ae_dt509 where field13 < to_timestamp( 2013-06-15 00:00:00, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' )* is throwing **Bind Variable "00" is NOT DECLARED** because the date is not enclosed in '' quotes